# Minimum sample size needed for A/B testing

Tags: sample-size, ab-test

Glossary:

- Sample SD = standard deviation of the samples that you currently have (control group). We havent started the treatment yet so we should not use the SD of the treatment group.
- MDE = "minimum detectable effect" = estimates the smallest improvement you are willing to be able to detect.

---

Problem:

I am getting a gigantic value and not sure why.

The shortcut formula to get the minimum sample size needed for treatment and control groups is:

`16*sample_SD^2 / MDE^2`

- The metric of interest is # of purchases.
- The sample_SD of the **control group** is 185 purchases.
- The MDE is 3% increase in purchases.

If I plug these numbers in I get a crazy high amount of samples required per group, north of 600 million. What am I doing wrong here?

```
sd_sample = 185    
mde = 0.03
required_n_in_each_group = (16*sd_sample**2) / (mde**2)
required_n_in_each_group = 608632862.6163108
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot combine absolute (SD=185 purchases) and relative (difference=0.03) like that; you're trying to detect a difference of 0.03 *purchases* (assuming your formula is correct). Either express your difference as an absolute mean or everything in the % scale.

Comment: I see. And so if I change this to SD = 185 purchases, MDE = (0.03*average purchases in the control group), does that sound good to you?

Comment: It helps for the readers if you write it out more clearly what you mean. Terms like 'sample_sd" and 'mde'... describe them more clearly.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus added into the question!

Comment: @Katsu yes, that sounds sensible. The caveat is that this will no longer be the same relative difference if the actual number of purchases in your experiment turns out to be very different, but you cannot have it all: the flip side of that coin is that 3% might equally be a very different absolute number. Percent change, being multiplicative, also has some edge case behaviour (asymmetry, bound at -100%) that you won't see in the absolute scale, although you seem to be in a pretty safe range.

Comment: @PBulls hmm ok so if i were to do the reverse and use relative changes only, would i do: SD = 185/522 = 35% (522 is the mean), and MDE = 3%? I get a similar n (2177) so it seems correct?